# Remove event listener manually react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a scroll event listener and I want to remove it based on page URL, how can I handle it using in a hook component?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    function handleScrollEvent() {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        setHeaderIsVisible(true);
      } else {
        setHeaderIsVisible(false);
      }
    }
    if (props.location.pathname === "/") {

      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScrollEvent, true);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScrollEvent, true);
    }
  }, [props.location.pathname]);
```

Where I should define the handleScrollEvent to remove it from listener?

Comment: You are defining `handleScrollEvent` in the correct place. What is wrong on what you are doing?

Comment: @Vencovsky It doesn't work. I think may be it is redefining the function and passes a new function to removeListener. I am not sure!

Comment: Define what you mean by `It doesn't work`

Comment: Listener still exists and works after removing.

Comment: `Listener still exists and works after removing.` are you sure it's removing? What can be happening is that the effect isn't running because `props.location.pathname` isn't changing

Comment: No. if I add a console.log('removed') in the else block, it shows that the code reaches to removing part.

Comment: just check my answer. It will create a new `handleScrollEvent` function, but you already removed the old one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need to do is every time you add it, you also remove it.

When `props.location.pathname` changes, it will remove the event listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.location.pathname === "/") {  
      function handleScrollEvent() {
        if (window.scrollY > 100) {
          setHeaderIsVisible(true);
        } else {
          setHeaderIsVisible(false);
        }
      }

      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScrollEvent, true);  
      // every time you add it, you also remove it when props.location.pathname changes
      return () => {
           window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScrollEvent, true);
      }
    }
  }, [props.location.pathname]);
```

Comment: No, I don't want to remove listener on component unmount. I remove it based on current location.

Comment: @HadiRanjbar try this. You will only have the event listener when `props.location.pathname === "/"`

Comment: @HadiRanjbar: Why do you want to keep this event listener around if the component has been unmounted? That seems like it would cause a memory leak.

Comment: @HåkenLid this component is header and it never is going to be unmounted.

Comment: @Vencovsky It surprisingly works and I have no idea why!

Comment: Then your first comment is even more confusing. useEffect will execute the cleanup before every update when `props.location.pathname` has changed. And also on unmount. It's explained in detail in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Comment: @HadiRanjbar just keep in mind one thing. `Every time you add a event listiner, you need to remove it` and with hooks, you should remove it returning a function that calls the remove event listener (clean up of `useEffect`)